# Mongoose - populate a single document by its ID

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have model called category and it has 2 fields
**category name** & **books**

The books field is an array of IDs of books **((refrences))**

I want to specify an id when calling the .populate() to be populated instead of populating the whole array in MongoDB + Mongoose

My code:

```
categories.get('/bookId', async (req, res) => {
    const bookId = req.params.bookId;
    try {
        const categories = await Category.find().populate('books') 
        if (!categories || categories.length == 0) return res.status(404).send("No categories found");
        res.status(200).send(categories);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you have tried so far. Thanks.

Comment: The code populates the whole array, we want to use the param (bookId) to populate a specific book with it's id from the books array instead of populating the whole array

Comment: categories.get('/bookId', async (req, res) => {
  const bookId = req.params.bookId;
  try {
    const categories = await Category
      .find()
      .populate('books')
    if (!categories || categories.length == 0)
      return res.status(404).send("No categories found");
    res.status(200).send(categories);
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error.message);
  }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to populate only the specific book by its ID then you could use [match](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#query-conditions) like this:

```
categories.get('/bookId', async (req, res) => {
    const bookId = req.params.bookId;
    try {
        const categories = await Category.find().populate({
            path: 'books', 
            match: { _id: bookId }
        }) 
        if (!categories || categories.length == 0) return res.status(404).send("No categories found");
        res.status(200).send(categories);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send(error.message);
    }
});
```